# Two Sum LeetCode problem error: 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'twoSum''

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self, nums, target):
        self.nums = nums
        self.target = target
        

    def twoSum(self):
        for i in range(len(self.nums)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(self.nums)):
                if nums[j] == self.target - self.nums[i]:
                    return [i, j]

num1 =  [[2,7,11,15],9]
num1.twoSum()
print(num1)
```

Why does this code produce the following error?

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'twoSum'
```

Comment: `num1 = Solution([2,7,11,15], 9); num1.twoSum()`

Comment: BrokenBenchmark gives a great answer to show you how to fix your code. To understand this better, I suggest you read more about classes.

Answer (score 1):

The code you were given is one of these, depending whether you chose Python 2 or Python 3:

```
class Solution(object):
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        """
        :type nums: List[int]
        :type target: int
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
```

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
```

You're supposed to implement the `twoSum` method, not add an `__init__` method and change the signature of the `twoSum` method.

After implementing that correctly, if you want to test it locally, do it like this:

```
print(Solution().twoSum([2,7,11,15], 9))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's two issues with your code:

1. You need to construct a `Solution` object rather than a nested list in order to invoke `twoSum()`.
2. The `if` statement in the `twoSum` function should use `self.nums` rather than `nums`, referring to the attribute that you set in the constructor.

Here is a code snippet that fixes both issues:

```py
class Solution:
    def __init__(self, nums, target):
        self.nums = nums
        self.target = target
        

    def twoSum(self):
        for i in range(len(self.nums)):
            for j in range(i + 1, len(self.nums)):
                if self.nums[j] == self.target - self.nums[i]:
                    return [i, j]

sol = Solution([2,7,11,15], 9)
print(sol.twoSum()) # Prints [0, 1]
```